# Can't add some shortcuts folders to the dock

Tags: macos, dock, folders, ui

Very strange situation I have two folders that I can't add to the dock in macosSierra, I can add all the other folders correctly.

I check the library\Preferences\com.apple.dock.plist but they aren't too.

I don't now where can I check to solve this problem, the preferences of this folders are the same to the others.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Operating systems can sometimes do strange things. One of the things I've seen with macOS when it comes to the Dock is that it can sort of *glitch* when you've been adding lots of items. This seems to happen moreso with folders (especially if you've added one, removed it, and then tried to add it back again).

What always resolves this glitch when I see it, is a simple reboot of the Mac. After rebooting, it accepts the folder. So I'd try restarting your Mac and seeing if that's what the problem is in this case.

Comment: Thanks, the first that I tried its restart the computer but the problem persists. 

Probably the error its related in reference that you say, because I erased this folders before and I couldn't add again. There are a afp links that I changed the location on the server but I use the same name. 

The situation it's that I don't know where can I check in macOS to solve the problem, if I add a similar folder in the same area of the dock this works correctly.

Comment: When you say _the same area of the Dock_, what do you mean by this? Where in the Dock are you trying to put these folders?

Comment: Sorry for my very late answer! This problem only success when I add a shortcut in the dock from network folder and only if it's an AFP connection. Because when I add the same shortcuts with a SAMBA connection I can add correctly(with local folders too). In AFP case I can add only one shortcut, when I add another one I can't: example video: [link] (https://youtu.be/lJNfeatXqYA)  Maybe it's because the QNAP Nas AFP sharing.